# Solving 2d quantum gravity as a TQFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory

I am considering (Euclidean) 2d quantum General Relativity in the functorial language of TQFT. Specifically, the theory is completely defined by associating a vector space with a circle, and an $n$-valent tensor (amplitude) to a 2d surface with $n$ punctures (that is, bounded by $n$ circles). Since 2d TQFTs are equivalent to symmetric Frobenius algebras, I infer that if 2d quantum gravity has a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, then it is a Frobenius algebra, and the only remaining question is – which algebra.

There's also a possibility that the vector space associated with a circle is infinite-dimensional, in which case 2d quantum gravity is an infinite-dimensional generalization of a Frobenius algebra. I don't know much about these structures, but I imagine that many properties of Frobenius algebras still hold.

To answer the question "which Frobenius algebra?", we need to provide three ingredients:

1. The motivation for the choice of the vector space associated to a circle.
2. The amplitude associated to a 3-valent surface (aka "pants"). In the Frobenius algebra language this corresponds to a choice of product and coproduct.
3. A vector in the vector space associated to a disk (2d analogue of the Hartle-Hawking state). In Frobenius algebra language this corresponds to a choice of the unit and counit (trace).

All other amplitudes follow from the gluing axiom of Atiyah-Singer, or, equivalently, from the structure of the Frobenius algebra.

By physical intuition, the vector space should somehow encode the quantum information about the 1d geometry of the circle. Phase space of GR is coordinatized by spatial metric components and corresponding canonical momenta, so after polarization, the wavefunction should be a diffeo-invariant function of the 1d metric. Easy to see that such functions can only depend on the circumference of the circle. So I expect the vector space to be infinite-dimensional and admit an interpretation in terms of superpositions of circle "Universes" with different circumferences.

I would love to see this line of thought to give any quantitative results coming from the quantum averaging over 2-geometries.

Does this construction make sense? Has it been studied? Can it be solved in the framework of random surfaces (using Liouville CFT)? Do you know any papers attempting to obtain the answer?

Comment: I have no idea if this is really related to your question, but there is a very new paper by very authoritative guys: http://inspirehep.net/record/1667061